# How do I created a LinkedList structure in C

Tags: python, c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a LinkedList Data Structure in C by using Struct. Below I have two examples, one that works and one that doesn't.

Firstly, the python version is what I'm trying to recreate with C (which is below python), and yes this is the peace of code that is working. I'm trying to get my C version to work but I'm not sure what wrong with it. Could someone try to solve my problem? or even provide a better solution? Thanks in advance!

### Python version

```
class Node:
    pass

start = Node()
point = start

point.val = 1
point.next = Node()
point = point.next

point.val = 2
point.next = Node()
point = point.next

point.val = 3
point.next = None
```

### Attempt in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    int val;
}; 

int main() {
    struct Node start;
    struct Node pointer = start;    
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct Node another;
        another.val = i;

        pointer.next = &another;

        pointer = *(pointer.next);      
    }   

    pointer = start;
    // Print out the value
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", pointer.val);
        pointer = *(pointer.next);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to read the chapter dealing with dynamic memory allocation (functions `malloc`, `free` and friends) in your C text book.

Comment: BTW [google](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* a linked list node */
typedef struct {
    int data;
    node *next;
} node;

/* represent a linked list as a pointer to the first node */
typedef node *list;

/* create a list by building first node */
list mklist(int firstData)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data = firstData;
    n->next = NULL;  /* the last node of the list always has next as NULL */
}
/* obtain a pointer to the tail node of a linked list */
node *getLast(list l)
{
    node *cur = l;
    while (cur->next != NULL)
        cur = cur->next;

    return cur;
}
/* add to the end of the linked list */
void append(list l, int newNodeData)
{
    node *last = getLast(l);

    last->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    /* last->next represents our new node. We set its data to newNodeData,
       and since it is the last node, its next member is NULL */
    last->next->data = newNodeData;
    last->next->next = NULL;
}
```